# What is the difference between Shapechange and Wild Shape?

Tags: spells, druid

I am a new D&D player and about to start my first campaign as a Circle of the Moon druid. My question is, when I reach level 9, what the difference is between the 9th-level transmutation spell Shapechange and the Circle of the Moon's innate ability to Wild Shape? They seem the same to me but I doubt they are...

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. What RPG and edition are you playing? If it's D&D 5e, you should edit the [dnd-5e] tag into the post. Also, what confuses you about the differences between the two, as laid out in their respective descriptions?

Comment: I have just added the 5e tag because (from my recent research) druid circles did not exist in earlier editions. please correct me if they did.

Comment: @rpgstar [we don't add system tags without confirmation from OP](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/what-to-do-when-an-edit-guesses-the-system-being-used-rather-than-waiting-for-th)

Comment: Thanks @NautArch, will remember that for next time